# WPF MVVM: Returning selected ListBox item on User Control back to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a list of devices displayed on a user control with a 'select' button. The list data comes from a parent ViewModel, and I'd like it such that the user selects which device they want, they hit the 'select' button, and the button command returns the selected device.

Additionally, I'd like a radio button or rectangle that changes colors to denote and work in step with the active selection (i.e. you can select either the radio button and the ListItem gets selected or click the ListItem and the radio button gets selected).

I have the binding working to the ListBox so it displays devices, but I can't figure out how to get the binding to work so the selection returns.

Here's what I'm working with:

#### View Model

```
// Props
private MutlipleAttachedDevicesModel _selectedDevice;
public MutlipleAttachedDevicesModel SelectedDevice
{
   get { return _selectedDevice; }
   set
   {
      _selectedDevice = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
   }
}

// Methods
public void DisplaySelectDevices()
{
    // Create new display
    DeviceSelectionVM = new DeviceSelectionViewModel();
    CurrentView = DeviceSelectionVM;

    // Populate Device List
    DeviceList = PopulateDeviceList();

}

private void CreateDummyData()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    var count = 0;   

    // make a max of 3 devices
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       DeviceList.Add(new MutlipleAttachedDevicesModel()
       {
           Name = "SP-2 Super Processor",
           Serial = $"SP2-00"+ r.Next(100).ToString(),
           IsSelection = false,
           WasUpdated = false
       });

       // First Device defaults to selected
       if (i == 0)
           DeviceList[i].IsSelection = true;

       count++;
    }
}

private void SelectTargetDevice(object selection)
{
    // Display Target Device
    var count = DeviceList.Count;

    for (var i=0; i<=count; i++)
    {
        if (DeviceList[i].IsSelection == true)
        {
            SelectedDevice = DeviceList[i];
            break;
        }        
    }

    Trace.WriteLine("Selection was "+ SelectedDevice.Serial);
}
```

#### ListBox

```
<ListBox x:Name="MultipleDeviceSelectionList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DeviceList, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding IsSelection, 
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}, 
                   Mode=TwoWay}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

           <RadioButton  GroupName="radio"  
                         IsChecked="{Binding IsSelection}" />

           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>

           <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock>
                 Serial #: 
              </TextBlock>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Serial}"/>
           </StackPanel>

           <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding WasUpdated, 
                                   Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}, 
                                   FallbackValue=Hidden}">
              Up To Date
           </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectButtonCommand, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                  AncestorType=Page}}">
   Select
</Button>
```

I've also tried other ways like attempting to two-way bind the radio button to the ListBox's SelectedItem property but honestly, complex binding is still confusing for me. What do I need to do to get the radio button stay in step with the list selection, and return the list selection properly?

Comment: Why don't you bind **SelectedDevice** to the SelectedItem property of the listbox directly ?

Comment: IsSelection is of type bool, but you bound it to SelectedItem which is type Device. Bind it to selected device.

Comment: What is `IsSelection` and why do you bind to it?

Comment: At first, I didn't realize ListBox had a selection mechanism so I was using `IsSelection` to set a default selection on the list and that was how I planned to figure out what the user selected.

Comment: @AthulRaj, Sorush: See, I didn't even realize you could do this. I'm stuck in the mindset of binding a single property such as 'Name' that it's hard to make that leap and understand binding can set the Selected Model into SelectedDevice.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ListView SelectedItem binding.
You want to bind to the SelectedDevice property.

```
<ListBox x:Name="MultipleDeviceSelectionList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DeviceList, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDevice, 
                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}, 
                   Mode=TwoWay}">
```

But maybe you should really check if the property is of the correct type because "MutlipleAttachedDevicesModel" doesn't seem like a model for a single device. Also i am not sure if you need the RelativeSource on that binding.

Comment: Fabian P: Thank you, this works! So how do I get either the radio button or a rectangle to work in step with the list selection? What do I need to bind those properties to? The `SelectedItem` property of the ListBox?

Comment: Also, "MultipleAttachedDevicesModel" is correct, it's a model I created for this purpose to only have the parameters I needed for this job. I've actually since changed this all into "Device Model" because I will actually need all of this information to persist the lifespan of the application.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I simply changed the radio button binding to:
`<RadioButton  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"/>` !